# CreateThread handle leak

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

`CreateThread` returns a `HANDLE` object that need to be closed by `CloseHandle`

The documentation states that `The thread object remains in the system until the thread has terminated and all handles to it have been closed through a call to CloseHandle.`

My question is **what happens if the return variable is not used**. It equals with not closing returned handle and because of this with a handle leak? It's that correct ?

Comment: Avoid hoping for the faeries to take care of it.  If an winapi function returns a handle then it's your job to release it.  And of course, you *always* want to check if the call failed.

Comment: Unless you need to wait for the thread to exit at some later stage, the simplest thing is to just CloseHandle(hThread) after calling CreateThread, and then you don't need to worry about it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It equals with not closing returned handle and because of this with a handle leak? It's that correct ?**

Yes, You will be leaking Operating system resources, this is analogous to leaking memory when you have a memory leak.

Reference:
**[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**:

> Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or remove the thread object. Closing a process handle does not terminate the associated process or remove the process object. To remove a thread object, you must terminate the thread, then close all handles to the thread.